# How to allow chrome browser notification in protractor e2e test for my Angular 9 web application

Tags: protractor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX39z.png)I need to allow the notification for the chrome browser to get incoming message notifications on my PC.

I have tried this code in the protractor.config file. It was still displaying the pop

```
capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
'chromeOptions':{
    'prefs' : {'profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation': }
},
```

I have also tried using the following code in spec, it is not working

```
browser.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

for this code, I am getting an error as No such alert was found and the scripts fail.

Is there any provision to allow notification pop in the protractor for the chrome browser?

Comment: what kind of notification is this?

Comment: Allowing the browser notification for new incoming video call notification and chat As well  to allow camera and mic access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geolocation` has nothing to do with it. You need to try these options https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7e762c1f17514a29834506860961ba2f24e7e6e5/components/content_settings/core/common/pref_names.cc#36 Most likely these 3

```
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream";
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic";
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera";
```

try these capabilities

```
{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        prefs: {
            'profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream': 2,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 2,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the chrome prefs but it still does not work for me. I have added an image for better understanding my notifications was it for the same or is there any different option for it let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the link it helped me and the prefs '    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications";  worked for me .
'